# Problem with Opera and jquery keydown return false

Tags: jquery, opera

I´m trying this on Opera 10 and doesn´t work:

```
$('input').keydown(function(){ return false; });
```

This works fine in other browsers.

Can anybody tell me something about this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [key events compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) table. Opera does not cancel a keypress when `keydown` preventsDefault. Use the `keypress` event instead to cancel keyboard input.

(Although, this is rarely a good idea. Intercepting keypresses does not stop a field being changed by other means than keys, for example drag and drop. Set the readonly or disabled properties true to properly stop the value being changed.)

Comment: Thanks!!

You are right. This is only an "ornament". 

I want the input only for integers values. Then, I check it on submit and in server side too.

Thank you again!

Comment: Kete: you can use <input type="number"> per HTML5 if you want integers ;)
However, I see Opera doesn't prevent alpha input - it just fails to submit it. We should do something more intelligent here.. :-p